Profile is not registered with auto created User via signals
I have a django application where the following model named Employee plays the role of the user Profile that is in relation with the User from the auth module:
class Employee(models.Model):

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    is_chef_de_project = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )
    is_chef_de_produit = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )
    is_ghr = models.BooleanField(
        default=False
    )

    account = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        null=True
    )

I want to automatically to create a User during registration of an Employee so I created the following signals.py file:
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth import hashers
from django.dispatch import receiver
from .models import Employee


def generate_password():
    import secrets
    import string
    alphabet = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
    return ''.join(secrets.choice(alphabet) for i in range(10))


@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    breakpoint()
    if created:
        uname = instance.first_name[0].lower() + instance.last_name.lower()
        passd = generate_password()
        User.objects.create(employee=instance, username=uname, password=passd)
        print("generated credentials:" + uname + ":" + passd)


@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
def save_user(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    breakpoint()
    instance.account.save()

But after registration I find the account attribute in the created Employee instance null:

Any hints what's going on? I was expecting the User instance created to be referenced by the registered Employee.

Run a database query to confirm that this behaviour is not Django Admin UI specific. If it is, this will probably answer your question.

It is funny, User has attribute employee, but in database the relation stored in Employee model.
In your case:
@receiver(post_save, sender=Employee)
def create_user(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if not instance.account_id:  # o2o is empty
        uname = instance.first_name[0].lower() + instance.last_name.lower()
        passd = generate_password()
        instance.account = User.objects.create(username=uname, password=passd)
        print("generated credentials:" + uname + ":" + passd)
        instance.save()  # recursive signal, but account_id should be not more empty

My opinion, the logic here is a bit broken because you're using signals, and that in itself is bad practice. But it should work.
As an answer, how it can be organized:
class Employee(User):
    phone = models.IntegerField(blank=True)
    is_chef_de_project = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_chef_de_produit = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_ghr = models.BooleanField(default=False)

Thats all. User will be created automatically. No signals, no any other code. Ths is Django Multi-table inheritance feature. More about it here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance
As additional, i offer you to set Employee as auth_user_model, more here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Thank you @maxim that worked just fine, and if you can elaborate more on what do you mean by the relation (employee) is stored in Employee? and what would be considered best practice in this situation instead of signals ?

@hamdi - i add "Best Practice" in my answer.
